# What key do I use with the OEM recovery partition?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, oem

Is the key just built into the partition and will resolve automatically? Or do I have to locate somewhere? I don't believe mine came with a key in the packaging. (though its not a new computer so I may just have lost it if it did.)

Any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Many OEM systems come with the key already embedded in the installation system.

Alternatively there should be a label somewhere attached to the computer with the key on it:

[image: Example windows key location]

Alternatively the program [KeyFinder](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/) may be able to tell you your current OEM key before you reinstall the system.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a certificate of authority sticker on your machine somewhere that will have the key on it.  If it's an old machine it may have just worn away, and I've noticed lately that these are sometimes located underneath the battery to prevent that from happening.